# cakePHP 3 app.php file security vulnerability

Tags: database, security, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am planning to deploy a site made using cakePHP. I know that the database info is stored in config/app.php without any security. It contains the username and password info. So I'm wondering when the site is live, if someone gets into my server maybe via a FTP, he/she can access app.php to access the db details. Is this the most secure way?

Comment: On your production server do the following: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production
If somebody already has ftp access to your files, than he can do a lot of harmful things, this is not a cake security issue. Most of the php systems store database crendentials as text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rrd